# SVG upload does not work

Tags: uploads, svg

I have created an SVG with clickable areas to be used as landing page image, The size of the file is 4 MB. I cannot upload it, Wordpess says there is an error (no specifics). Size seems not to be the problem, other files of this size are uploaded.

I have the SVG Support plugin installed.

I used lnkscape to create it. It looks fine in Edge and does what it is supposed to. I tried all SVG formats that are available in lnkscape but all fail.

I do not use Media Library Assistant.

Where could I start looking what the problem is?

Could the theme I use be the problem (Thefour)?

Bear with me if this is really trivial - I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't allow to upload SVG files by default.

**Add svg file type in allowed file types list**

```
function wp_mime_types($mimes)
{
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'wp_mime_types');
```

**Fix for displaying svg files in media library**

```
function wp_fix_svg() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        .attachment-266x266, .thumbnail img {
         width: 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
        }
        </style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wp_fix_svg' );
```

**Attempt to determine the real file type of a file**

```
function wp_check_filetype($data, $file, $filename, $mimes) 
{
    global $wp_version;
    if( $wp_version !== '4.7.1' ){
        return $data;
    }

    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );

    return [
        'ext'             => $filetype['ext'],
        'type'            => $filetype['type'],
        'proper_filename' => $data['proper_filename']
    ];
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wp_check_filetype', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thanks that was quick!

I forgot to mention: I have the SVG Plugin installed, but that did not change anything (I updated my initial question now). Probably some pretty important information, sorry!

Question: Do I add this code to custom CSS oder functions.php?

If the latter is necessary, I might have another problem because I cannot locate this file in the themes folder of the theme I currenty use. I tried other themes in the past and for some I see a folder structure with all files, for others I only see a link that seems to lead nowhere. How is that even possible?!

Comment: You can try to deactivate SVG Plugin and paste code from my answer to your functions.php. At least will know if problem related to this plugin.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!